How to determine which 'hwmon' folder in 'sysfs' contains the sensor data?
I have an 'sht3x' temp/humidity sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi via I2C. I've written a bash script to get the sensor readings from sysfs. My problem is this: the name of the folder containing the sensor files I need to read changes, and I don't know how I should get the correct folder name. IOW: Which folder in sysfs contains the files with the sensor measurements and configuration parameters?
I wired and configured (via RPi's device tree & overlays in config.txt) the sht3x to take up residence on channel i2c-0 at bus address 0x44. I confirmed that using i2cdetect -y 0.
Using grep, I found the sysfs folder I needed at the following location:
/sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon3

I did some research to sort out how that particular folder was instantiated/selected to contain the results - but my research was not entirely successful. Here's what I worked out:

/sys/bus/i2c/devices is the "root" for all I2C devices that the system knows of

0-0044 corresponds to the i2c "channel" I selected (i2c-0), and the device address (44)

hwmon is the "root" sysfs folder for all I2C sensor devices


But that still leaves me lacking one folder: hwmon3. This folder has changed names a few times; typically after a reboot. This final folder name usually alternates between hwmon3 & hwmon2, but I imagine that may change if I add other sensors.
I could add a grep routine into my bash script to find the correct folder, but I can't help but think "there must be a better way to do this". In the kernel document "Rules on how to access information in sysfs", the author(s) suggest using udev to navigate sysfs - but AFAICT there is nothing in udev for I2C devices. So - that's my question: How do I get the kernel to tell me what sysfs folder my sensor data is in?

The hwmon devices will also be symlinked in the /sys/class/hwmon directory, e.g. /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3 -> ../../devices/..some../..thing../hwmon/hwmon3 which might make them easier to find, although you still have the problem of working out which one you are interested in. Perhaps the contents of the name attribute or the symlink target path will help.

You can also set an optional label attribute in the device tree node for the hwmon device, which appear in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmonN/label if it has been set.

@IanAbbott: Hey - thanks for that...  when you say "in the device tree node", where exactly is that located?

In the node for the I2C client device, i.e. the node for the hwmon device, probably something like sht3x@44 { compatible = "sensirion,sht3x"; reg = <0x44>; status = "okay"; }. You can add a label = "whatever"; property inside that node.

@IanAbbott: I'm not sure how that makes it persistent, but thanks anyway.

The 0-0044 is uniquely defines the device, there can’t be other hwmon folders, so you can take whatever is there, it doesn’t matter what number it has. /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon* is enough.

@0andriy Unless there is more than one I2C bus being instantiated in parallel and it is random which one gets assigned the number 0.

@Seamus Persistence is relatively easy to deal with for /dev (using symlinks created by UDEV rules), but I do not know of an equivalent mechanism for /sys. The label would help a script iterate and detect the correct device path in /sys if the path is not persistent.

@IanAbbott, there is always the way how to detect bus (adapter) uniquely. sysfs has all means for that.

@0andriy But bus numbering is dynamic, so if there is more than one I2C bus, it is possible the hwmon device could end up on /sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0044/hwmon/hwmon*.

@IanAbbott said, "the hwmon device could end up on /sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0044/hwmon/hwmon."*  -  Uh, no - at least not in Raspberry Pi - It will always be on i2c0, and it will always be at address 0x44. The only variable is hwmonN.

@IanAbbott said, "Persistence is relatively easy to deal with for /dev (using symlinks created by UDEV rules)". Mmmm... not entirely true. I've progressed a bit with this problem, but still can not get a rule that I know filters correctly to create a SYMLINK+=. See my related question. It seems udev won't add a symlink in /dev for devices in the hwmon subsystem (? "subsystem" may be an incorrect term for hwmon, but you get my meaning I hope)

@IanAbbott, see wider, I was taking about sysfs in general, and not about that particular path. The adapter path is unique and fixed, when you know it, the address on the bus is also unique. It just requires more iterations to get all what’s needed.

Why do you think the hwmon does provide file operations, i.e. can be located in dev? I mean have you checked that it registered with respective major and minor combination?

@0andriy: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I've posted the answer I found below.

@0andriy Yes, at least for "geographic" properties such as a fully qualified branch on a PCI tree, or a devicetree, or an ACPI tree, although some parts of the path may still be indeterminate, such as the 3 in hwmon3.

@IanAbbott, are you assuming that there is a possibility for one device have two or more hwmon interfaces? If so, is it documented somewhere? Do we have examples / use cases IRL for such a configuration? Otherwise, that 3 makes no difference as long as the hwmon node is a single one per sensor device.

@0andriy I suppose there might be a possibility of having two hwmon child devices (I haven't checked), but that's not what I meant. I just meant that the last component (basename) of the hwmon device name might not be deterministic even if the names of all its ancestors are deterministic. Although assuming only one child device can be a hwmon device, it would be the only entry (apart from . and ..) within a hwmon\ subdirectory (e.g. hwmon\hwmon3). I.e. it would need to be matched as a wildcard even if everything else is deterministic.

@0andriy Apologies for using backslashes. Of course I meant hwmon/, not hwmon\.

I'm posting this answer b/c I have made progress on my question, but an issue remains:
In my question, I opined "there must be a better way [than grep to locate my sensor device file in sysfs]". I wondered if udev was a solution, but I have never seen a udev example that was applied to a device on an i2c bus. All the examples one finds concern themselves only with disk drives (or the occasional network device)!
Anyway, I read a bit about udev, found nothing stating that it was incapable of dealing with i2c-based sensor devices, and decided to have a go at it. I was successful, but the solution involved a detour.
Here's my "solution" - such as it is:
Create a .rule file at /etc/udev/rules.d/80-local.rules with one line:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hwmon", ATTR{name}=="sht3x", KERNELS=="0-0044", SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'ln -s /sys$devpath /dev/hwmon_sht3x'" 

I have tested this rule several times now, and it accomplishes my objective: I get a symlink to the correct folder in sysfs. I have forced "the system" to move/rename the sensor folder from /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon3 to /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2 to /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon4. In each case, the symlink produced in /dev by the above rule was correct. This gives me a persistent location for the sensor data in /dev/hwmon_sht3x
The symlink I get in /dev is as follows:
hwmon_sht3x -> /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon<X>

where <X> is the correct number; "2, 3 or 4" on my system.
If you're familiar with udev rules, you may be wondering why I didn't use the SYMLINK+= assignment key - instead of the RUN+= assignment key with a sh command to create a symlink?
The answer is: the SYMLINK+= assignment key did not create a symlink of any kind in /dev! I wonder if this has something to do with the fact it's in the hwmon SUBSYSTEM???
I've read through all the udev documentation I could handle, but found no answer why this is so. Perhaps it's a bug? I don't know... but if you know the answer, I'd love to hear from you.

Since symlinks in /dev usually point to special device files or to other symlinks in /dev,  it might be better to create them in somewhere like /run, but it doesn't really matter. I think the reason the SYMLINK+= assignment did not work is because the hwmon susbsystem does not create special character devices so there are no /dev/hwmonN files to link to.
